More products by the same author - Product Page woocommerce
On the product page, I would like to add a section identical to "Related products", except that only products with the same product should be displayed in the loop. Authors are created as a custom taxonomy.
How can I achieve this?
I have already modified the "related products" section to display products from the same series, but I would like to duplicate this module for another taxonomy.
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_from_esporte_taxonomy', 10, 3 );
function related_products_from_esporte_taxonomy( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
    $taxonomy     = 'seria-wydawnicza'; 
    $term_ids     = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); 
    $term_slugs   = array(); 

    if ( count( $term_ids ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $term_ids as $term_id ) {
            $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, $taxonomy )->slug; 

            // Gets the IDs of child terms
            $children_ids = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );

            foreach ( $children_ids as $child_id ) {
                $term_slugs[] = get_term_by( 'id', $child_id, $taxonomy )->slug; // Gets the slug of each child term
            }
        }

        $related_posts = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'        => 'publish',
            'tax_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $term_slugs,
                ),
            ),
            'return'        => 'ids',
            'exclude'       => array( $product_id ),
            'visibility'    => 'catalog',
            'limit'         => -1,
        ) );
    }

    return $related_posts;
}

